# How to show that the maximum depends on a given parameter

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

How to show that the following maximization problem has a unique solution, that depends on parameter $a$ (without using differential calculus): $f(x, y)=y-\frac{1}{x}$ subject to $a x+y \leq 1, x \geq 0, y \geq 0$, where $a>0$?

We know that it must be shown that the constraint is a continuous, compact-valued correspondence. Because $f$ is continuous and strictly quasiconcave and the maximum problem has a unique solution. The Theorem of the Maximum implies that this solution depends continuously on $a$. However, we would like to prove it mathematically. Can you help us?

Comment: What do you mean by "without using differential calculus"?

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{cases} f(x,y)=y-\frac 1x\\ ax+y\leq1\end{cases}$$

We may write:

$$ax+y-\frac 1x \leq 1-\frac 1x$$

Or:

$$f(x,y)=y-\frac 1x \leq 1-\frac 1x-ax=\frac{x-1-ax^2}x$$

So  $f(x, y)$ is maximum when RHS is maximum.Let:

$u=\frac{x-1-ax^2}x$

$u'=\frac{x(1-2ax)-(x-1-ax^2}{x^2}$

$u'=\frac{1-ax^2}{x^2}=0$

which gives:

$x=\pm \frac 1{\sqrt a}$

1): $x=+\frac 1{\sqrt a}$

From inequality we have:

$a\cdot(\frac 1{\sqrt a})+y\leq 1$

For maximum we consider equality $ax+y=1$ and check:

$y=-a\cdot (\frac 1 {\sqrt a})+1=1-\sqrt a$

putting in $f(x, y)$ we get:

$f(\frac 1{\sqrt a}, 1-\sqrt a)= \sqrt a -1-\sqrt a=-1$

This is minimum of $f(x, y)$

2): $x=-\frac 1{\sqrt a}$, we have:

$a\cdot(-\frac 1{\sqrt a})+y-1=0$

Which gives:

$y=1+\sqrt a$

Putting in $f(x, y)$ we obtain:

$f(-\frac 1{\sqrt a}, 1+\sqrt a)=1+\sqrt a+\sqrt a=1+2\sqrt a$

This  is maximum of $f(x, y$ which is a function of parameter $a$.

Using calculus we get:

$\begin {cases}\frac 1{x^2}+ a \lambda=0\\1+\lambda=0\\ax+y-1=0\end {cases}$

Which gives:

$\lambda=-1$, $x=\pm \frac 1{\sqrt a}$ and $y=\sqrt a-1$ and $y=1+\sqrt a$ which are similar results.

Comment: Hi sirous, I believe that there is a more theoretical approach using the theorem of the maximum and the idea of correspondence (uhc,lhc), without using  differential calculus